# Getting a selected row's background color to change when using EditCommandColumn button in a GridView

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

I've tried a few things, including the SelectedItemStyle and inline CSS.  Here's what I currently have:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
     <style type="text/css">
        .hoverTable tr:hover {
                        background-color: wheat;
        }

        .hoverTable tr:current {
                        background-color: aquamarine;
        }

        .SelectedTable {
                        background-color: aquamarine;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <div id="divGrid" style='width:920px; height:230px; overflow:auto'>
            <asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid_ClaimSearch" runat="server"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                    CssClass="hoverTable" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged"
    OnCancelCommand="DataGrid_ClaimSearch_CancelCommand" 
    OnUpdateCommand="DataGrid_ClaimSearch_UpdateCommand" 
    OnEditCommand="DataGrid_ClaimSearch_EditCommand">
        <AlternatingItemStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <EditItemStyle BackColor="#999999" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="Teal" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />

        <Columns>
            <asp:EditCommandColumn ButtonType="PushButton" CancelText="Cancel" 
                    EditText="Select" UpdateText="Update"></asp:EditCommandColumn>

            <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status" />
            <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="LPI Review Date" DataField="Status_Date" />
            <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="LPI State" DataField="LPI_STATE" />
            <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Paid Date" DataField="Claim_Paid_Date" />
            <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Paid Amount" DataField="Claim_Paid_Amount" />
            <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="LPI Amount" DataField="Total_LPI_Amount" />
            <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="LPI_ID" DataField="LPI_ID" ItemStyle-Width="0px" />

        </Columns>

            </asp:DataGrid>
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty" runat="server" Visible="false" Style="font-weight:bold; font-size:large;"></asp:Label>
    </div> 
</asp:Content>
```

The CSS in the header won't change the row that's selected.  The SelectedItemStyle tag inside the GridView won't change the row that's selected.  Adding RowStyle-CssClass to the GridView didn't help either.  The tr:hover CSS works fine.  I can't find any examples of changing a row's selected style when using an EditCommandColumn button.  Any help is appreciated.

BTW, this is part of an Intranet web page built with C#, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Ah well.  I figured it out as soon as I offered the bounty.  Sux to be me...

Anyway, for posterity's sake, here's the answer.

In the `DataGrid_ClaimSearch_EditCommand` void, I added this line:

```
e.Item.BackColor = Color.FromName("#E56E94");
```

Easy as that!

Comment: The `EditItemStyle` works fine when I tested your snippet.